# Javascript function is executed before it is called

Tags: javascript, function, meteor, simple-schema, meteor-collection2

I have a javascript function complaining that a call within its body is not a function before it is called. Could someone please help me explain this?

Context: I am using [Meteor](https://www.meteor.com) and [Collection2](https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-collection2) and I would like to use a function for reuse at different attributes of my Schemas. Precisely, I would like to do the following:

```
function foo (autoVal, self){
  if(something){
     return autoVal;
  }else{
     return self.unset();
  }
}

export const myCollection = new Mongo.Collection('myCollection');

const Schema = new SimpleSchema({
   my_field:{
      type:Boolean,
      autoValue: foo(false,this),
   }
});

myCollection.attachSchema(Schema);
```

When I save  this and run Meteor, it does not launch and I get the following error message:

`TypeError: self.unset is not a function`

I feel that I am missing something about how javascript functions are called or executed, can someone point out why is this happening?

Comment: There is not enough there to reproduce whatever problem you are having. You should check out http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and [MCVE]

Comment: figure out what `this` is when this code is executed `autoValue: foo(false,this);` - oh, and realise that foo is executed before `new SimpleSchema` is called (also that's not valid javascript, seems like the `;` at the end of `foo(false, this);` should not be there at all

Comment: `this` is not the `this` you're looking for.

Comment: It was a context issue with ```this``` indeed, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
function foo (autoVal, self){
  if(something){
     return autoVal;
  }else{
     return self.unset();
  }
}

export const myCollection = new Mongo.Collection('myCollection');

const Schema = new SimpleSchema({
   my_field:{
      type:Boolean,
      autoValue() {
        return foo(false, this);
      }
   }
});

myCollection.attachSchema(Schema);
```

Comment: That worked thanks! I'll accept the answer soon it needs at least 7 mins to do so